# How to render a plotly object in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, render

I am attempting to plot an array of integers given to react front end of the site from the asp.net backend. Specifically it comes from a controller. I can create a heatmap object using this array of integers. I would like to render this object in the JSX if possible. I am unable to map it to html as it is only one object.

Currently i am creating the plotly heatmap in the renderHeatMap function. The site can render the plot but throws the following error: " Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. "

Is what I am attempting possible in the App.js portion of the site?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Plotly from './plotly.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { binaryData: [], loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateWeatherData();
    }

    static renderHeatMap(binaryData)
    {
        var heatMap = [
            {
                z: [binaryData.slice(0, 7658134), binaryData.slice(7658135,15316269)],
                type: 'heatmap'
            }
        ];

        let heatMapObj = Plotly.newPlot('heatMapSection', heatMap);

        return <div> {heatMapObj}</div>
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading... Please refresh once the ASP.NET backend has started. See <a href="https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact">https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact</a> for more details.</em></p>
            : App.renderHeatMap(this.state.binaryData);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Weather forecast</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }

    async populateWeatherData() {
        const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ binaryData: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to this problem. You can return a plotly object as an html object. This is an optimal solution as the relationship between the App.js and index.js is not violated since the App.js will only return an html object and not attempt to render objects. Here is a link to the repository i used https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/ . Below i have included an example from this repository on how to return an plotly object as HTML.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            x: [1, 2, 3],
            y: [2, 6, 3],
            type: 'scatter',
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            marker: {color: 'red'},
          },
          {type: 'bar', x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 5, 3]},
        ]}
        layout={{width: 320, height: 240, title: 'A Fancy Plot'}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```